# Recursive function to compare strings without library functions

Tags: c, string, function, recursion

I'm supposed to write a recursive function in C programming language that checks if string 1 is greater than or equal or less than string 2, and thus returning `1`, `0`, `-1` respectively.

Below is my code that I've written. The program cannot terminate and I cannot figure out the reason. Please give me some advice. Thank you.

```
int revisedStrcmp(char *s1, char *s2) {
    int i = 0, n = 0, p = 0;

    if (s1[i] == '\0' && s2[i] != '\0') //s1 shorter than s2
        return -1;

    else if (s1[i] != '\0' && s2[i] == '\0') //s1 longer than s2
        return 1;

    else if (s1[i] != '\0' && s2[i] != '\0')  //both not equal to null
    {
        if (s1[i] > s2[i])  n += 1; //s1
        else if (s1[i] < s2[i]) p += 1; //s2
        else
        {
           n += 1; //s1
           p += 1; //s2
        }
        i += 1;
        return revisedStrcmp(s1, s2);
    }
    else    //if s1[i] & s2[i] are null
    {
        if (n > p) //s1 > s2
            return 1;
        else if (n < p)
            return -1;
        else
            return 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The main problem in your function is you do not pass updated pointers in the recursive call to `revisedStrcmp`, causing an infinite loop and a potential *Stack overflow*.

Here is a corrected and simplified version:

```
int revisedStrcmp(const char *s1, const char *s2) {
    if (*s1 < *s2)
        return -1;
    if (*s1 > *s2)
        return +1;
    // *s1 == *s2
    if (*s1 == '\0')
        return 0;
    return revisedStrcmp(s1 + 1, s2 + 1);
}
```

There is no need to make special cases for shorter strings because the null terminator can be used in the comparisons.

This particular style of recursion is called tail recursion and will be compiled into a loop by modern compilers.

Note however that for `revisedStrcmp()` to return the same order as `strcmp`, the comparisons must be performed on `unsigned char` values instead of plain `char`, which can be signed by default on many architectures:

```
int revisedStrcmp(const char *s1, const char *s2) {
    unsigned char c1 = *s1, c2 = *s2;
    if (c1 < c2)
        return -1;
    if (c1 > c2)
        return +1;
    // c1 == c2
    if (c1 == '\0')
        return 0;
    return revisedStrcmp(s1 + 1, s2 + 1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Reason is that `s1` and `s2` are the same in recursion. What I mean:
if you have `char *s1 = "Hello";` and `char *s2 == Elloh`, your recursive calls are the same. you start at the same point, always, you do not pass increments in any way  `(n, p)` so you are basically starting from same point every recursive call. What you can do is increment pointer and here is short solution:

```
int revisedStrcmp (char *s1, char *s2) {
    if (*s1 == *s2)
        return *s1 == '\0' ? 0 : revisedStrcmp(s1 + 1, s2 + 1);

    return (*s1 > *s2) ? 1 : -1; 
}
```

or you can do following:

```
return revisedStrcmp(s1+i, s2+i);
```

Comment: @chqrlie Is this what you meant? That is a good idea, thank you!!! In case where they are different yes it saves 2, but I also can get away with one test case less in other cases. What I mean is that I can get away with not testing if `*s2 == '\0'` because if '*s1 == *s2` and `*s1 = '\0'` it automatically means that `s2 = '\0'`

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing to the function the `i, n, p` variables. In that way your function will not end, because it will start every time with the counter variables at 0.

Answer (score 0):

In the part:

```
    else if (s1[i] !='\0' && s2[i] !='\0')  //both not equal to null
    {
        if (s1[i]>s2[i])  n+=1; //s1
        else if (s1[i]<s2[i]) p+=1; //s2
        else
        {
           n+=1; //s1
           p+=1; //s2
        }
        i+=1;
        return rStrcmp(s1,s2);
```

you call `rStrcmp(s1,s2);` with `s1` and `s2`, however, you have just processed a character. Call `rStrcmp(s1+1,s2+1);`.

---

Note: since your function processes only one character per call, you don't need to index the strings with `i`. It is always 0 except before a return statement, so its value is never used:

```
int rStrcmp(char *s1, char *s2)
{
    if (*s1 =='\0' && *s2 !='\0') //s1 shorter than s2
        return -1;

    else if (*s1 !='\0' && *s2 =='\0') //s1 longer than s2
        return 1;

    else if (*s1 !='\0' && *s2 !='\0')  //both not equal to null
    {
        if (*s1>*s2)  return 1; //s1
        else if (*s1<*s2) return -1; //s2
        else
            return rStrcmp(s1+1,s2+1);
    }
    else    //if s1[i] & s2[i] are null
    {
        // since both are null, they are the same length and each
        // character was the same: equal
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change the `return rStrcmp(s1, s2);` to `return rStrcmp(s1+i, s2+i);`. So that way you are storing the increments of your array position.